# Limit inferior and superior of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I just can't understand the concept of $\lim \sup/\inf$ of sets, even after reading a lot about it. In limit infinum why do we have union sign with intersections (infima)? Can someone explain it very easily? Thank you very much.

Comment: No, sorry. I know there are a lot of questions like this, but i dont understand the answers

Comment: It would help *us* to help *you* if you can say something about *what* you don't understand in these answers. Otherwise you're just going to get a whole lot of the same answers from those "a lot of questions like this". In fact, writing out *exactly* what you don't understand might just end up making you understand.

Comment: I dont understand the definition. In lim inferior definition(union of intersactions) in wikipedia is said" So the limit infimum contains all subsets which are lower bounds for all except finitely many sets of the sequence." This is what i dont get..

Comment: But we are not asking what you don't understand *on Wikipedia*. We are asking what is unclear in the many answers that you say that you've read *on this site*. The more details you [edit] into your question, explaining exactly what confuses you, the easier it is to give you an answer (or point you at the direction of an older post).

Comment: I already said.

Comment: No. You haven't. You pointed me to Wikipedia, when I asked about content on *this site*.

Comment: There is definition that is used, I dont want to write it so i refer to wikipedia, i said what i dont understand

Comment: I asked you what you don't understand in the *answers*. Not in the definition. There are many answers that explain this definition, I want to know *how* these answers are not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a sequence that represents a function of time.  Suppose further that this sequence is the sum of two separate contributions: transient and steady state.  The transient part of the signal is the part that has a limited time presence.  The steady state part of the signal is the part that goes on forever.

For example, consider the following function
$ f(x) = exp( -x / 10 ) + sin( x )$

Note that the exponential part of the signal dies away to $0$, while the sin part of the signal stays around forever.

Intuitively, limit superior and limit inferior are asking what are the supremum and infimum after all of the transient parts have died away.

Comment: Hm,thank you. But how i think about limit superior/inferior when i have intersection of union of sets?  When looking in wikipedia : "So the limit supremum is contained in all subsets which are upper bounds for all except finitely many sets of the sequence". What is meant by that?

Comment: Where in wikipedia does it say that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior

Comment: in Special case: discrete metric

Comment: do you understand what the discrete metric is? There is a lot written in that section, so it would help if you could be more specific about which part of it you don’t undertand